# Can I make Redactor add a 'title' attribute to img-tag?

Tags: redactor

If I add an image to a rich-text field, I can set it's title. On the front-end however, the img-tag only gets an alt-attribute. I would also like the title-attribute to be set. Is this possible with a Redactor config-file, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

None of the [settings you can put in your Redactor config-file](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/) will do what you want. You **can** write a [redactor plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins-creating/) to do this, and then include your redactor plugin as a Craft plugin. One Craft plugin that does this is [RedactorClips](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips/).

If your Craft plugin is *mycraftplugin*, and your redactor plugin files are *myredactorplugin.css* and *myredactorplugin.js*, then you store the redactor plugin files in the `resources` directory of your craft plugin, and in the craft plugin `init()` function, you call:

```
craft()->templates->includeCssResource('mycraftplugin/myredactorplugin.css');
craft()->templates->includeJsResource('mycraftplugin/myredactorplugin.js');
```